# Filling an array and calling super

Tags: java

Now I have this class:

```
public final class MyClass<T> {

    public MyClass(Function<Number, Function<Number, T>> func, Number rows, Number cols) {
        final T[][] result = (T[][]) new Object[rows.intValue()][cols.intValue()];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows.intValue(); ++row) {
            for(int col = 0; col < cols.intValue(); ++col) {
                result[row][col] = func.apply(row).apply(col);
            }
        }
        super(result);
    }
}
```

But call to `super()` must be first statement in constructor body. Is it possible to change the body of the method so that the constructor is valid?

The static method for filling the array did not work because of generics.

```
private static Object[][] fillArray(Function<Number, Function<Number, Object>> func, Number rows, Number cols) {
    final Object[][] result = new Object[rows.intValue()][cols.intValue()];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows.intValue(); ++row) {
        for(int col = 0; col < cols.intValue(); ++col) {
            result[row][col] = func.apply(row).apply(col);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`super((T[][])fillArray(func, rows, cols));` - wrong first argument type. Found `F<Number, F<Number, T>>`, required `F<Number, F<Number, Object>>` (F - Function).

Comment: Can you show the issue that you had with a static method?

Comment: Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor. [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: @MalusJan That exact thing is right in the question. "But call to super() must be first statement in constructor body." The asker is trying to figure out how to get around it, which is tricky because of the generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extract the result code into an own static method:

```
public final class MyClass<T> {

    public MyClass(Function<Number, Function<Number, T>> func, Number rows, Number cols) {
        super(result(func, rows, cols));
    }

    private static <Z> Z[][] result(Function<Number, Function<Number, Z>> func, Number rows, Number cols) {
        final Z[][] result = (Z[][]) new Object[rows.intValue()][cols.intValue()];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows.intValue(); ++row) {
            for(int col = 0; col < cols.intValue(); ++col) {
                result[row][col] = func.apply(row).apply(col);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Note, that the static method is a generic method itself. To make that clear, I have used another type variable (`Z`).

Answer (score 1):

The code you have appears to be self-contained, and your issue with using `static` was probably just related to not declaring the proper generic types. You could try this:

```
public final class MyClass<T> {

    private static <R> R[][] transform(Function<Number, Function<Number, R>> func, Number rows, Number cols) {
        final R[][] result = (R[][]) new Object[rows.intValue()][cols.intValue()];
        for (int row = 0; row < rows.intValue(); ++row) {
            for(int col = 0; col < cols.intValue(); ++col) {
                result[row][col] = func.apply(row).apply(col);
            }
        }
    }

    public MyClass(Function<Number, Function<Number, T>> func, Number rows, Number cols) {
        super(transform(func, rows, cols));
    }
}
```

The `<R>` declares a generic type within the scope of the `static` method and is unrelated to the `<T>` on `MyClass<T>`. If you wanted to, you could change the `<R>` on the method to anything you wanted, e.g. `<T>`, `<E>`, or even `<MyGenericType>`, and it would still work.